# How to create sequence for two columns on pgsql

Tags: postgresql, query, trigger, postgresql-performance, sequence

I have a table

```
 CREATE TABLE public.mytable (
    sequence integer NOT NULL,
    caller_address TEXT,
    contract_address text,
    contract_sequence integer,
    value integer,
    CONSTRAINT mytable_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("sequence")
 );
```

and sequence

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_next_contract_sequence_mytable() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $insertnextcontractsequencemytable$
    BEGIN
       NEW.contract_sequence = COALESCE((SELECT MAX(contract_sequence) + 1 FROM mytable WHERE mytable.contract_address = NEW."contract_address"), 0);
       RETURN NEW;
    END;
$insertnextcontractsequencemytable$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER table_contract_sequence_mytable
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON public.mytable
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_next_contract_sequence_mytable();
```

I am using this contract sequence to query for pagination on frontend like this

```
SELECT sequence, contract_address, caller_address, value
    FROM mytable
    WHERE contract_address = $3 AND contract_sequence <= $2
    ORDER BY contract_sequence DESC LIMIT $1
```

How can I create new_sequence if I have to query for two columns like this?

```
   SELECT sequence, contract_address, caller_address, value
        FROM mytable
        WHERE (contract_address = $3 OR caller_address = $3) AND new_sequence <= $2
        ORDER BY new_sequence DESC LIMIT $1
```

Comment: Querying for a maximum and adding 1 is not a reliable way to manage sequential values in a database that allows concurrent access. There is no guartantee that another process isn't inserting into the same table in a concurrent transaction. Each query will see the maximum as it was at the time its transaction started and will therefore attempt to insert the same value. If the affected column has a unique constraint, then at most one of the inserts will succeed.